# using Select2 with Durandal

Tags: durandal, single-page-application

Hi I am trying to use Select2 (multiselect) with Durandal (http://jsfiddle.net/anasnakawa/6XvqX/381/),
but the popup does not work below is part of my VM and HTML, here I am trying to bind a list of states to an input it should work as an auto complete but there seems to a issue showing the selection popup, can someone please help

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/datacontext', 'plugins/router', 'services/bindinghandlers'],
function (app, datacontext, router) {
    var withs = ko.observableArray(),
        states = [
    { id: "AL", text: "Alabama" },
    { id: "AK", text: "Alaska" },
    { id: "AZ", text: "Arizona" },
    { id: "AR", text: "Arkansas" },
    { id: "CA", text: "California" },
    { id: "CO", text: "Colorado" },
    { id: "CT", text: "Connecticut" },
    { id: "DE", text: "Delaware" },
    { id: "FL", text: "Florida" },
    { id: "GA", text: "Georgia" },
    { id: "HI", text: "Hawaii" },
    { id: "ID", text: "Idaho" },
    { id: "IL", text: "Illinois" },
    { id: "IN", text: "Indiana" },
    { id: "IA", text: "Iowa" },
    { id: "KS", text: "Kansas" },
    { id: "KY", text: "Kentucky" },
    { id: "LA", text: "Louisiana" },
    { id: "ME", text: "Maine" },
    { id: "MD", text: "Maryland" },
    { id: "MA", text: "Massachusetts" },
    { id: "MI", text: "Michigan" },
    { id: "MN", text: "Minnesota" },
    { id: "MS", text: "Mississippi" },
    { id: "MO", text: "Missouri" },
    { id: "MT", text: "Montana" },
    { id: "NE", text: "Nebraska" },
    { id: "NV", text: "Nevada" },
    { id: "NH", text: "New Hampshire" },
    { id: "NJ", text: "New Jersey" },
    { id: "NM", text: "New Mexico" },
    { id: "NY", text: "New York" },
    { id: "NC", text: "North Carolina" },
    { id: "ND", text: "North Dakota" },
    { id: "OH", text: "Ohio" },
    { id: "OK", text: "Oklahoma" },
    { id: "OR", text: "Oregon" },
    { id: "PA", text: "Pennsylvania" },
    { id: "RI", text: "Rhode Island" },
    { id: "SC", text: "South Carolina" },
    { id: "SD", text: "South Dakota" },
    { id: "TN", text: "Tennessee" },
    { id: "TX", text: "Texas" },
    { id: "UT", text: "Utah" },
    { id: "VT", text: "Vermont" },
    { id: "VA", text: "Virginia" },
    { id: "WA", text: "Washington" },
    { id: "WV", text: "West Virginia" },
    { id: "WI", text: "Wisconsin" },
    { id: "WY", text: "Wyoming" }
        ];
    var vm = {         

        withs: withs,            
        states: states,

    };

    return vm;
});

<select multiple="true" data-bind="options: states, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'text', selectedOptions: withs, select2: {}" style="width: 300px"></select>
```

Comment: Where is your select2 custom binding handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register `select2` in the Require.js configuration inside main.js:

   ```
   requirejs.config({
     paths: {
       'select2': 'path/to/select2'
     }
   });
   ```
2. Define it in your view model:

   ```
   define(['select2'], function (select2) {
     // ...
   });
   ```
3. Don't forget to declare it. You'll have to use the `attached` callback:

   ```
   var vm = {
     withs: withs,
     states: states,
     attached: function() {
       $('select').select2();
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: I don't mean to sound harsh, but this is a perfect situation for a custom binding handler.  By using the attached event you are going to have to put a ton of code in the viewmodel that is for DOM manipulation./

Comment: Yes, you're right. Especially if you're handling multiple selects on the same page. I realized it as I was looking over the jsFiddle that OP provided.